# Android - How to properly change Actionbar title via Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

The default code generated when one tries to implement a navigation Drawer activity in Android Studio follows the paradigm:

```
    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = ...
```

Is there a way for me to avoid hard-coding this? To utilize `R` fields and names already given to the Drawer entries ("Section 1", "Section 2" etc) so as to be picked regardless of their possible count? Ideally I would like to have this part as generic as possible and even work with **different sets of Drawer entries** (Navigation Drawer Fragments?).

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: You can use the ActionBar object and use it like this- mActionBar.setTitle(R.string.your_title);

Comment: @amitsingh I know that, but I am looking for a way know which title to use so that the main activity class is independant of the drawer's contents.

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreate method of each fragment that will be opened, you can use getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Whatever you want");

getSupportActionBar() in case of support libraries.

I am not clear what you want when you say generic fragments. Maybe if you can tell me something specific that is in your mind.

Comment: I want the user to be able to select one of the nav. Drawer items(a list which may chance at runtime) and then, depending on his choice, set up a different fragment layout on my main activity and change the ActionBar title the user sees.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom navigation drawer adapter? Further you can store values in tags and later retrieve them to set as title. I think this should work in theory although I haven't tried it myself.